# cross checking - consolodating pandas dataframes (pd.concat, pd.merge don't seem to work in this case)

Tags: python, pandas, validation, merge, concatenation

I am trying to combine two data sets the complement each other in some instances into a new dataframe without duplicating columns. In other words, I have two dataframes. In certain columns (that have the same name in both dataframes), the information I need will be in either one, but not both.

For example, see the following imaginary dataframes that I created that mirror the issue at hand. These dataframes contain information of the same 3 people. Pay attention to the 'gender' column. When the value is missing in one, it is found in the other and vice versa. The combination of the values of both columns gives us a complete gender column. ideally, I would get df_need below.

(The actual datasets have quite a few columns like gender)

```
df_have1 = pd.DataFrame({'age':[7,34,19], 'gender':['F',np.nan,'M'], 'profession':['student', 'CEO', 'artist']})
df_have1

df_have2 = pd.DataFrame({'age':[7,34,19], 'gender':['np.nan','F',np.nan], 'interests':['acting', 'cars', 'gardening']})
df_have2

df_need = pd.DataFrame({'age':[7,34,19], 'gender':['F','F','M'], 'profession':['student', 'CEO', 'artist'], 'interests':['acting', 'cars', 'gardening']})
df_need
```

I tried pd.concat, which unfortunately duplicates the gender column. So does pd.merge and join.

```
pd.concat([df_have1, df_have2], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more generic code adapted from the @Rob Raymond sugestion

```
def replace_str_nan_by_np_nan(df_str_nan):
    """
        dealing with nan strings, since fillna handles only np.nan
        
        Args: df with string nan
        
        Return: df with np.nan
    
    Ex: 
        import pandas as pd
        import numpy as np
                
        df_str_nan = pd.DataFrame({
            'age':['np.nan',34,19], 
            'gender':['Nan',np.nan,'M'], 
            'profession':['student', 'nan', 'artist']})
        df_np_nan = replace_str_nan_by_np_nan(df_str_nan)              
        print(df_np_nan.isna())
            age     gender  profession
        0   True    True    False
        1   False   True    True
        2   False   False   False
    """
    import numpy as np
    
    df_np_nan = df_str_nan.copy()
    for nan in ['np.nan', 'NaN', 'Nan', 'nan']:  
        df_np_nan = df_np_nan.replace(nan, np.nan, regex=True)
        
    return df_np_nan


def join_df1_df2_repeated_col(df1, df2):
    """
        join two dataframes keeping values within repeated columns 
        dealing with nan strings, since fillna handles only np.nan
        
        Args: df1, df2 two dataframes
        
        Return: df_join joined dataframe
    
    Ex: 
        import pandas as pd
        import numpy as np
        

        df1 = pd.DataFrame({
            'age':[7,34,19], 
            'gender':['F',np.nan,'M'], 
            'profession':['student', 'CEO', 'artist']})
        df2 = pd.DataFrame({
            'age':[7,34,19], 
            'gender':['np.nan','F',np.nan], 
            'interests':['acting', 'cars', 'gardening']})

        print(join_df1_df2_repeated_col(df1, df2))
        
            age gender  profession  interests
        0   7   F       student     acting
        1   34  F       CEO         cars
        2   19  M       artist      gardening
    """
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    
    
    # dealing with nan strings, since fillna handles only np.nan
    df1 = replace_str_nan_by_np_nan(df1)
    df2 = replace_str_nan_by_np_nan(df2)
    
    rsuffix = "_r"
    df_join = df1.join(df2, rsuffix=rsuffix)
    
    # dealing with repeated columns
    mask = df_join.columns.str.endswith(rsuffix)
    lst_col_r = list(df_join.loc[:,mask].columns)
    for col_r in lst_col_r:
        col = col_r[:-len(rsuffix)]
        df_join[col] = df_join[col].fillna(df_join[col_r])   
    
    return df_join.drop(columns=lst_col_r)


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'age':[7,34,19], 
    'gender':['F',np.nan,'M'], 
    'profession':['student', 'CEO', 'artist']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'age':[7,34,19], 
    'gender':['np.nan','F',np.nan], 
    'interests':['acting', 'cars', 'gardening']})

join_df1_df2_repeated_col(df1, df2)
```

Answer (score 3):

- `merge()` or `join()` will work with column **suffixes**
- use data to `fillna()`
- drop unwanted columns once done

```
df_have1 = pd.DataFrame({'age':[7,34,19], 'gender':['F',np.nan,'M'], 'profession':['student', 'CEO', 'artist']})

df_have2 = pd.DataFrame({'age':[7,34,19], 'gender':['np.nan','F',np.nan], 'interests':['acting', 'cars', 'gardening']})

df_need = (df_have1.join(df_have2, rsuffix="_r")
 .assign(gender=lambda dfa: dfa.gender.fillna(dfa.gender_r))
 .drop(columns=["age_r","gender_r"])
)
```

|  | age | gender | profession | interests |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7 | F | student | acting |
| 1 | 34 | F | CEO | cars |
| 2 | 19 | M | artist | gardening |

Answer (score 0):

By far the @Rob Raymond approach is better.

But, if the both dataframes have the same number of rows, you can achieve a similar result with dictionaries and for loops (poor practice within Pandas framework).

```
df_have1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'age':[7,34,19], 
    'gender':['F',np.nan,'M'], 
    'profession':['student', 'CEO', 'artist']})
df_have2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'age':[7,34,19], 
    'gender':['np.nan','F',np.nan], 
    'interests':['acting', 'cars', 'gardening']})
df_need = pd.DataFrame({
    'age':[7,34,19],
    'gender':['F','F','M'],
    'profession':['student', 'CEO', 'artist'],
    'interests':['acting', 'cars', 'gardening']})

dct = {k:{} for k in (list(df_have1.columns) + list(df_have2.columns))}
for col in dct.keys():
    if col in list(df_have1.columns):
        for row in df_have1.index:
            if col in list(df_have2.columns):  # intersection
                if df_have1[col].iloc[row] not in ['NaN', np.nan]:
                    dct[col][row] = df_have1[col].iloc[row]
                elif df_have2[col].iloc[row] not in ['NaN', np.nan]:
                    dct[col][row] = df_have2[col].iloc[row]
                else:  # without NaN values in the entry
                    dct[col][row] = np.nan
            else:  # data only in df_have1
                dct[col][row] = df_have1[col].iloc[row]
    else:  # data only in df_have2
        for row in df_have2.index:
            dct[col][row] = df_have2[col].iloc[row]

df_get = pd.DataFrame(dct)

assert df_get.equals(df_need)  # assures the both df are the same
```